# Change font size of lstlistoflistings heading

Tags: sectioning, listings, chapters

How can I change font size of `lstlistoflistings` heading? Currently it is smaller than normal chapter heading title. Any ideas?

Unfortunately I need to use document class from my university, my MWE:
MWE:

```
\documentclass{aghdpl}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}


\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java, caption=Caption,label=lst:registry]
public interface IRegistry
{
    void Register(Device device);
    List<Device> GetAll();
    Device GetByUuid(UUID uuid);
}
\end{lstlisting}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Listings}
\lstlistoflistings

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibliografia}

\end{document}
```

Document class is available here: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5400ba9cf95f88391849bde8

When I've used `article` document class lstlistoflistings had same size as chapter size so probably it is connected to the document class :(. Unfortunately my tex knowledge is to small to solve this issue.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It's set as a `\chapter*`, which should be the same as the rest of the chapters. Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem seeing as it's otherwise unlikely to be resolved. Your MWE should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Jubobs I've added MWE and more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your `aghdpl.cls` class file, you'll see that chapters are set using a font size `\LARGE` (line 191-192):

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\bfseries\LARGE}{\filright \LARGE\thechapter. }{0ex}{}
```

However, ToC-related entries are set using only `\Large` (line 209):

```
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\bfseries\Large}
```

Since `\lstlistoflistings` is set just like your regular `\tableofcontents`, it will be smaller. You can adjust `\cfttoctitlefont` to match that of regular chapters by adding

```
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\bfseries\LARGE}
```

somewhere in your document preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass{aghdpl}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{listings}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\bfseries\LARGE}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java, caption=Caption,label=lst:registry]
public interface IRegistry
{
    void Register(Device device);
    List<Device> GetAll();
    Device GetByUuid(UUID uuid);
}
\end{lstlisting}


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Listings}
\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution is the answer. Have a nice weekend.